# How to use getExternalStorageDirectory() to load multiple songs from internal storage

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I'm working on custom mediaplayer app which must load the songs from both SD card and internal storage. I searched everywhere to find a way to load songs from Internal Storage, most of post which i checked out were just using `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` for loading a single MP3 file not multiple. I'm able to load all songs from  SD card (Memory Card) but not able to load from Internal Storage. Is there any way to load all the songs stored inside of internal storage?

My code,

```
 private void loadSongs() {
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

    Uri uriPath;

    String MEDIA_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/";

    String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + "!=0";
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, selection, null, null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME));
                String artist = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST));
                String url = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));

                Log.i("DATA111", MEDIA_PATH);

                mediaMetadataRetrieve = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
                mediaMetadataRetrieve.setDataSource(MEDIA_PATH + "/Music/");

                art = mediaMetadataRetrieve.getEmbeddedPicture();

                if (art != null) {
                    songImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(art, 0, art.length);
                }

                SongInfo s = new SongInfo(name, artist, url, songImage);
                _songs.add(s);

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        cursor.close();
        songAdapter = new SongAdapter(MainActivity.this, _songs);

    }
}
```

Here you can see that I'm using `MEDIA_PATH` which is a String type variable where `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` is used to load multiple songs but all I get is `IllegalArgumentException` error (Yea I can cleary see that I'm getting `IllegalArgumentException` which means something is wrong with the path and I tried to fix it but I was not able to do so) .

Can anyone tell me a way to load all the songs from Internal Storage in my custom mediaplayer? By the way correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: try this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39051474/how-to-get-all-mp3-files-from-internal-and-external-storage-in-android

Comment: @AndroidTeam i tried this method given by you. When i runt he app, it do not show mp3 files but only .ogg files (All of them were .ogg no file was mp3). do you have any solution that can let my musicplayer to load mp3 not .ogg

Comment: @AndroidTeam I have phone with 64GB internal storage and no SDcard slot. When I run that code you gave me, it crashes my app. But when I changed `Uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;` to `Uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;` it loads all `.ogg` files but no mp3 files.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void getSongs(Context context, String location){
    Uri songUri = ((location == "internal")?
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI:
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

    //Query devices for files (This class provides applications access to the content model.)
    ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();

    //This interface provides random read-write access to the result set returned by a database query.
    Cursor myCursor;


    //This is the information i want to get from all the songs on my device.
    //Columns for audio file that show up in multiple tables.
    String SONG_ID = MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID;
    String SONG_DATA = MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA;
    String SONG_TITLE =  MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME;
    String SONG_ARTIST = MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST;

    //This is what i'll retrieve from the song table.
    String[] songColumns = {
            SONG_ID,
            SONG_DATA,
            SONG_TITLE,
            SONG_ARTIST,
    };


    //Show music files only (IS_MUSIC returns Non-zero if the audio file is music).
    final String musicOnly = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC+"=1";

    myCursor = contentResolver.query(songUri, songColumns, musicOnly, null, null);

    if (myCursor != null && myCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        int songId = myCursor.getInt(myCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(SONG_ID));
        String songData = myCursor.getString(myCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(SONG_DATA));
        String songTitle = myCursor.getString(myCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(SONG_TITLE));
        String songArtist = myCursor.getString(myCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(SONG_ARTIST));

        do {

            Song song = new Song(songId, songData);

            song.setTitle(songTitle);
            song.setArtist(songArtist);


            //Add the song to the global ArrayList 'songList'.
            songList.add(song);

        } while (myCursor.moveToNext());
    }else{
        //What to do if no songs are found?
    }
    myCursor.close();
```

**Song Class**

```
public class Song implements Serializable {

  private long id;
  private String data;
  private String title = "";
  private String artist = "";


public Song(long songId, String songData){
    this.id = songId;
    this.data = songData;

}

public long getId(){
    return id;
}

public String getData(){return data;}

//Optional meta data

public void setTitle(String title){
    this.title = title;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setArtist(String artist){
    this.artist = artist;
}

public String getArtist() {
    return artist;
}
```

Comment: My code is similar to this one. I have a phone with 64GB internal space and whenever i start the app with this statement `MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)` it crashes but when i start it with this statement 
@Vince @AndroidTeam
`MediaStore.Audio.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)` it do not load a single song (MP3 file) but only some `.ogg` files. Is there anyway to fix this?