# Slow loading times in MusicPlayerApp

Tags: java, android, xml, performance, android-studio

Hey so I just made an android app which basically fetches all the mp3/wav files from your phone and then shows them it to you. Which you can then play them. But I am experiencing slow load times. My phone has like 10 mp3 and its a 6GB RAM phone. But it takes like 1 minute to load all those files. I am using the built in MediaPlayer Class. Any tips?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code.

for reference [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39073035/13560223)

```
  public void getMp3Songs() {

        Uri allsongsuri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " != 0";

        songsList.clear();

        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(allsongsuri, null, selection, null, null);

        if (cursor != null) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    String song_name = cursor
                            .getString(cursor
                                    .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    int song_id = cursor.getInt(cursor
                            .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID));

                    String fullpath = cursor.getString(cursor
                            .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));
                    songsList.add(fullpath);

                    String album_name = cursor.getString(cursor
                            .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM));
                    int album_id = cursor.getInt(cursor
                            .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID));

                    String artist_name = cursor.getString(cursor
                            .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST));
                    int artist_id = cursor.getInt(cursor
                            .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST_ID));


                } while (cursor.moveToNext());

            }
            cursor.close();

        }

        Toast.makeText(context, ""+songsList.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: Will that make loading fast?

Comment: yes off course this will work.